# Question about linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be an arbitrary vector space over the reals or the complex numbers, and let $L$ be a linear operator on $X$ such that $L^2=I$, where $I$ is the identity operator on $X$. Must it be true that $\ker(I+L)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{im}(I-L)$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: What is the definition of the kernel?  The image?  What does is mean to be a subset?  You've given us no evidence that you know any of these things, or that you have made any attempt to apply them to this problem.

Comment: Do you have any additional information that makes you believe that this must be true? Certain constraints, deifintions for instance, which you know and we do not?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

I think you reversed the inclusion.

Prove that 
$$f\circ g=0\iff \mathrm{im}(g)\subset \ker(f)$$
and notice that $$L^2=I\iff (I-L)\circ(I+L)=0$$

Comment: Nice observation and great answer.

Answer (score 0):

In finite-dimensional case, it is easy to check $\dim \textrm{Ker}(I+L)=\dim \textrm{Im}(I-L)$   ( by Jordan-block argument, for instance) and the obvious fact $\textrm{Im}(I-L) \subset \textrm{Ker}(I+L)$, hence  $\textrm{Im}(I-L) = \textrm{Ker}(I+L)$.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Is it an example for L such that Im(I-L) is a proper subset of Ker(I+L)?